# Searching and comparing data from two different csv files

Tags: python, csv

First of all, keep in mind that I'm a complete beginner with Python. I've been trying to figure this out all afternoon with no luck.

This is what I'm trying to do:

Let's say we have two csv files:

file 1:

```
col1;col2
659039;16,9
659038;27,8
659037:36,4
```

file 2:

```
col1;col2
659037:36,4
659039;16,9
659038;30
```

I want to search col1 of file 2 for all the items in col1 of file 1, and if it is found and there is a difference in col2, return that line. In the above case only the last line of file 2 would be returned, because the other lines are identical(line number doesn't matter). I only want those who are different.

Poorly explained. Hope you understand what I mean. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Separate input from logic. That means: read the csv file in and put it in the right data-structure in memory. Then compare those 2 data-structures.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do one thing at a time. First, extract all the values you need to check file2 for from file1 and store them in a data structure that is easy to work with. In the example below, I looped through all of the lines in file1 and collected the contents in a dictionary. Specifically, the keys are from column one and the values are from column two.

Now, you can loop through each row in file2 and try to find any row where the content in column one doesn't exist as a key in the dictionary.If the key does exist, make sure that its value doesn't match column two. Only when both of those conditions are satisfied should you return that line.

```
import csv

fileItems = {}
linesToReturn = []

with open('file1.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file1:
    reader = csv.reader(file1, True)
    for row in reader:
        fileItems[row[0]] = row[1]

with open('file2.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2, True)
    for row in reader:
        if fileItems.get(row[0]) != row[1]:
            linesToReturn.append(row)

print(linesToReturn)
```

If you're using csv to search through the files, check out the documentation [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Answer (score -1):

Break down your problem into sub-problems. You can use Pandas framework to achieve this in following steps-

1. Read the csv file.
2. Use pandas framework to compare both the columns. You can refer to - https://www.shanelynn.ie/python-pandas-read_csv-load-data-from-csv-files/
3. If you find the desired difference, add the line to python list
4. return the list at the end of the code.